# Default VM arguments in Eclipse debug configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I implement new features using TDD, I often use the shortcut `Shift + Alt + D T` to run only the jUnit test case I am currently working on (and not the whole test suite, which takes a few minutes).

This creates a new Debug Configuration for the current Java source and runs it immediately. Now I would like to run the test with assertions enabled (VM option `-ea`).

Unfortunately, the VM arguments for the new debug configuration starts empty. I always have to go into `Debug Configurations...` → `Arguments` and add `-ea` to the VM arguments input box.

Is there any way to have Eclipse these arguments populated with (project or workspace wide) default options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Windows` → `Preferences` → `JUnit` has an option to add `-ea` every time a new launch configuration is created. It adds the `-ea` option to the Debug Configuration as well.

The full text next to a check box is:

> Add `-ea` to VM arguments when creating a new JUnit launch configuration

Answer (score 40):

I think you can set this option by editing the definition of the JRE under `Preferences` → `Java` → `Installed JREs` → Select the JRE in question and edit the default VM arguments

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem, while it is not exactly the feature I was looking for. With this solution the "VM arguments" in the debug configuration stay empty, and the "default VM arguments" are added silently when launching.

I think, Eclipse should at least show the "default VM arguments" that are added in the debug configuration dialog. The downside is that you can't remove from the default VM arguments for a specific configuration (which is not the sense of default that I like :))

Answer (score 2):

Only way I can see to do it is to contribute a new launch configuration, this is not a trivial task but not too hard if you have PDE experience.

There is an [eclipse.org article](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Java-launch/launching-java.html) (see "Creating a Launch Configuration") that describes how to construct configurations and launch them.

I guess you could copy the JUnit implementation (see the org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes extension in org.eclipse.jdt.junit) and add in your chosen defaults to that config. You'd then need to declare a key binding to launch it and package the plugin to your install.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll consider creating a special launch configuration when I have some spare time (rarely ;-)).
I'll go with the answer by Grem for now (somehow I missed the default VM arguments field in the JVM config).