# Auto add VM arguments to any new JavaFx project is Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx-11

Every new JavaFx (11 or higher) project under Eclips, requires a VM argument in the "Run Configuration".
The information about it is available is the official [getting started guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) as well as in many SO Q&A such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52156678/3992939).

How do I automate it ? Have this VM argument added whenever I launch a JavaFx project (but **not** when I launch a Java project) ? 
How can I create a new run configuration template
(as explained [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debug/Plan/Launch_Configuration_Templates)) and have it associated with JavaFx projects ?

[image]

A similar question had been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62689802/how-to-avoid-adding-vm-arguments-everytime-i-create-a-new-javafx-project) , with no good answers. 
There are also related Q&A ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131594/default-vm-arguments-in-eclipse-debug-configuration), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639322/how-can-i-specify-the-default-jvm-arguments-for-programs-i-run-from-eclipse)) but they do not provide the solution I looking for.

Comment: The "default VM arguments" mentioned in both of the Q&A answers does this - what is the problem with that?

Comment: @greg-449  The problem is that default VM arguments are applied to all Java projects, but they are needed only for JavaFx projects.

Comment: You can have multiple installed JRE entries for the same JVM with different default args

Comment: I thought about installing another JRE but this looks a bit ugly to me. Or can it be done with one JRE ?

Comment: You can have multiple entries for a single JRE  - use the 'Duplicate...' button at the right of the Installed JREs preference page.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks. Duplicate and setting unique VM arguments to the other jre reference does work. However I still need to manually select this JRE to each new JavaFx run configuration.